# Is there a (intrinsic) way to invite particular users to join a newly created chat-room?

Tags: discussion, support

Much as the title says. I've decided to create a [new chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63250/enterprise-architect-lounge) today for a particular
tag ([enterprise-architect](/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect)) I want to promote.

I know there are some users around, that will be interested in discussions about this tag (or simply to meet the other enthusiasts about it).

Is there an accepted way to invite (notify about) these particular people to participate in this chat room? (The chat-room is public anyways)?

Comment: I'm failing to see any reason that arguments against a site-wide contact-another-user system don't equally apply to invite-another-user

Comment: Maybe just make an announcement in chat, and hope for it to be starred, and go from there? ....in any event, I doubt you'll convince many users who aren't already active in chat to join a SE chat room.